# How to integrate typesafe-i18n with Vite bundler?

Tags: typescript, internationalization, vite

It's inconvenient to turn on the generator for [typesafe-i18n](https://github.com/ivanhofer/typesafe-i18n). How to run it with Vite bundler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After version 5.0 of typesafe-i18n [there is no official way](https://github.com/ivanhofer/typesafe-i18n/discussions/227) to integrate generator to bundler build pipeline (previously it was available via webpack or rollup plugin).

Now you can run synchroniously generator and Vite bundler by importing cli script into your config:

```
export default async ({ mode }: ConfigEnv) => {
    const dev = mode === 'development';
    if (!dev) {
        process.argv.push('--no-watch');
    }
    await import(path.resolve('./node_modules/typesafe-i18n/cli/typesafe-i18n.mjs'));
// .. etc
```